# Is Quicksort "adaptive" and "online"?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

That is to say, does Quicksort perform BETTER when given an already sorted list? I don't see why this would be the case, but perhaps I don't understand exactly the algorithm.

Also, can quicksort "keep going" whilst we add new data to the list WHILE SORTING? Seems to me the algorithm needs the full set of all data at the beginning to "work".

Comment: What is your source on this?

Answer (score 2):

> does Quicksort perform BETTER when given an already sorted list?

No, in fact the way it's usually taught (use the first element as the pivot) an already sorted  (or nearly sorted) list is the worst-case.  Using the middle or a random element as pivot can mitigate this, however.

> can quicksort "keep going" whilst we add new data to the list WHILE SORTING?

No, your intuition is correct, you need the entire data set from the start.

Comment: "Using the middle" - I think you mean the median, if you always use the element in the middle of the array, we can construct worst case instances no problem.

Comment: No, I meant the middle element. Yes, we can construct worst-cases for it, but they're significantly less likely than a sorted array, and vanishingly small probability in larger arrays.

Comment: @G.Bach if you use median then you guarantee `O(logn)` iterations, but quicksort makes no such guarantee. Quicksort is `O(n^2)`. Finding the median each time is more expensive then the likely small number of extra iterations.

Comment: @Kevin "they're significantly less likely than a sorted array" - I very much doubt that, I would expect that for all policies of the kind "take the k-th element in the array", there is exactly the same number of worst case permutations. Unless by "likely" you mean something else than that.

Comment: @G.Bach Sure, the number of worst-case permutations is the same, yes, but I maintain that *in practice* a worst-case array for pick-the-middle is a great deal less likely for a general implementation (e.g. `qsort()`) than a (nearly) sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Quicksort perform BETTER when given an already sorted list

I think the performance of quicks sort majorly depends upon the choice of the pivot element at every step. It would be the worst if the pivot element which is selected is likely to be either the smallest, or the largest element in the list

> quicksort "keep going" whilst we add new data to the list WHILE
>   SORTING?

Yes quicksort is not adaptive. Thats the property of quick sort.

Answer (score 0):

Quicksort, when its choice of pivots is random, has a runtime of O(n lg n) where n is the size of the array. If its choice of pivots is in sorted order its runtime degrades to O(n^2). Whether you choose the pivot from the left side, right side, middle or randomly, it doesn't matter since it is possible, if not likely, to select pivots in sorted order.

The only way to avoid this is to guarantee the pivots aren't in order by using a technique such as the "Median of Three."

According to Robert Sedgewick, Algorithms, Addison-Wesley Publishing Company, 1988, page 124, if you use the Median of Three technique to choose the pivot and stop the recursion for small partitions (anywhere from 5 to 25 in size; this leaves the array unsorted but you can finish it up quickly with an insertion sort) then quicksort will always be O(n lg n) and, furthermore, run 20% faster than ordinary quicksort.